# Breakdown of correspondence principle: null dust case

Tags: general-relativity, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

In both quantum and general relativity theories we are used to provide results in the "limited" conditions to demonstrate a correspondence between new and old formalism.

For instance deflection of light of a star due to Sun in GR is double the amount given in classical theory.

Yet I have problems to sense a limit condition on the gravity due to pure radiation also called null dust solution of Einstein's field equation for a perfect pressureless fluid.

If we tend to zero both the masses on the Newton gravity law the force among the objects/particles will be zero.

But based on Einstein's field equation the energy momentum tensor does not vanish in the case of massless objects and is defined in terms of two null four velocities which is the equation for a dust with zero pressure. Therefore the nonvanishing curvature tensor says that a group of massless particles have gravity among themselves.

Is this a correct understanding?

And is it a counter example to correspondence principal in GR?

Comment: In relativity, unlike quantum mechanics, the correspondence principle isn't of great significance. You are quite correct that in GR massless particles do gravitate while in Newtonian gravity they don't. Most of us wouldn't consider this anything worth making a fuss about.

Comment: my point is that a correspondence cannot be made given the nature of Newton law.

Comment: Yes, I agree. So what?

Comment: I am trying to imagine what the cosmos looked like or its dynamics in the radiation dominated era after Big Bang. Thought that a correspondence with Newton law in the limits might be helpful.

Comment: You cannot understand how the universe evolved during the radiation dominated era without a proper general relativistic treatment. But then you can't understand how it is evolving right now without a proper general relativistic treatment.